# How to stop AWS glue from creating 1 individual table instead of multiple tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have folder structure as following in S3

- Data

  - table1/output/table1.csv
  - table2/output/table2.csv
  - table3/output/table3.csv

My ideal goal is to have a Glue Crawler to have 3 respective tables created. Instead what is created is 1 table called data with partitions table1, table2, table3 and output. I have messed around with various combinations in the configuration page but still no luck. Any recommendations?

Comment: Hey, could you give details about how you configured Glue to get one table with these partitions? Which other configurations did you try?

Comment: I've played around with , Create a single schema for each S3 path, as well what to do with messing around with schema changes but no luck in any of them.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Could you share your comment in your question instead?